# Is running an unpaired t-test on paired data conservative?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I have data that are repeated measurements.  But the biologist did not keep track of the pairing information.  It seems to me however that if you run an unpaired t-test on paired data that the worst thing that can happen is a loss of power.  In other words it should be a conservative thing to do so I can still reject the null hypothesis of a change in means between the two groups.

Or am I just dreaming and you simply cannot analyze paired data for which the pairing information has been lost?

Any insights at all would be much appreciated, thank you.